# Virtual host redirects to localhost in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, ubuntu-11.10

I have recently configured Virtual Host in my Ubuntu 11.10. 
But whatever site i type, it always redirects to the localhost page.

This is my "our-test-site" file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/zftut/public
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/zftut/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

and this is my, "etc/hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   our-test-site.local
127.0.0.1   zftut.local
127.0.1.1   System.B    System
```

Now when I try to go for "zftut.local", it redirects me to localhost page, showing me this:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

What am I doing wrong? I refered ["this"](http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/03/setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-apache-on-ubuntu-for-local-development/) tutorial for setting up virtual host.

Comment: What URL do you get redirected to?  What does the access and (debug-enabled) error logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show us your complete apache configuration. I think you still have the default VH definition.

You need to add the `ServerName` line:

```
ServerName www.zftut.local
ServerAlias zftut.local *.domain.tld
```

The `ServerAlias` is optional and helps you get to the correct VH for several names. In this example, all DNS names that ends with `zftut.local`. Of course, you need to setup proper DNS records (or line in hosts file) for each name you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, i had to add the servername and the server alias.. It worked.